# List of available sounds for iOS push notifications

Tags: ios, ios5, push-notification

I'm trying to change the sound for my push notifications, but I don't know what the names are to use.  I want to use the "electronic" sound, but what do I put in the sound field in my payload?  Is there a list of available sounds?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html), you can specify "default" as the value for your "sound" key in the payload to play the default sound, or the name of a sound file in your app bundle to play that sound. You'll need to [prepare the sound](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10) to make sure it's in a compatible format.

Comment: I was under the impression I could use one of the sounds already on the iPhone, is this not the case?

Comment: I've only ever seen `default` as a built-in sound. I tried googling around and couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's why I couldn't find any either.  I thought I had just missed them somehow.

Comment: Both the pages are not found. @kevboh

Answer (score -1):

The answer above may be wrong.

You CAN specify a built in sound, the problem I'm looking into is figuring out all the names.

This APNS Python code for example works:

```
APNSmessage = Message([u1.push_notification_token], sound="chime", alert=sender+" Private Messaged You: "+messagePushNotification, badge=u1.unread_badge_count, custom={'slug':slugChannel})
```

Notice that `sound` is set to `chime` and not `default`. This works for iOS 7 and above and don't see why not that it should work for iOS 8 as well.

When I first wrote this code I just took a wild guess and entered `chime` which, lo and behold, worked.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this result. As far as I could tell, specifying anything in the `sound` key — `default`, `chime`, or `asdf`, for example — will all play the system sound, unless the name of the sound is found in the main application bundle.