# iOS Push notification Custom sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I need to customize push notification sound. I don't want to create and include to Bundle. I need to implement like whatsapp notification sounds or please give a list of Apple provided sounds(like default sound). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of available sounds for iOS push notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709707/list-of-available-sounds-for-ios-push-notifications)

Comment: That is not looking proper answer for my question. I am looking some sample files of caf. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play custom sound file when user get push notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179630/how-to-play-custom-sound-file-when-user-get-push-notification)

Comment: Why you all writing it's a duplicate question ? he clearly say he looking for the same notification like whatsapp that provide by apple sounds. All the links you all provided suggestion server side or unrelated answer ! @Thangavel did you find the solution ?

Comment: @XcodeNOOB Thanks. I had included the sound files to the bundle. I didnt find any other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

After digging this issue for more than 3 weeks, and writing back and forth with apple this is the only solution
change payload to something like

```
 sound = "custom"
```

now you need to show all your system sounds in a table view (if you don't know how to do it, look on github). 
once the user mark his sound notification you need to copy the file to library/sound and give it the name of custom (or whatever the exact name in the payload).
that way you never change the server side code and you keep it on custom, and on the other hand you just overwrite the custom file with a new sound the user has been chosen.

*SIDE NOTE: on version 9.2.1 there's a bug which cause the notification not to work on the second time, or at all, it's should be fixed according to Apple in the next version 9.3 !

in the breath I wish the solution I could override the payload like we can do in Android, Apple makes push notification a lot harder on the developers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is the way finally i have implemented with custom sounds.

Answer (score 1):

in you bundle add a sound file named "pushSound.caf".

//write your payload this way

```
{
 aps =
 {
    alert = "message";
    sound = "pushSound.caf";//this file will have to your bundle
   };
}
```

Comment: he wrote he don't want to include bundle. this is not about server side, it's about customise the notification when you get it, the 'sound' parameter in the JSON should be 'default', and customisation should be in the app delegate. i've yet come to find how to override the default iOS system message received .

Answer (score 0):

**Preparing Custom Alert Sounds**

For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an app. The sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app’s data container.

Custom alert sounds are played by the iOS system-sound facility, so they must be in one of the following audio data formats:

- Linear PCM
- MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
- µLaw
- aLaw

You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in Xcode, add the sound file to your project as a nonlocalized resource of the app bundle or to the Library/Sounds folder of your data container.

You can use the afconvert tool to convert sounds. For example, to convert the 16-bit linear PCM system sound Submarine.aiff to IMA4 audio in a CAF file, use the following command in the Terminal app:

```
afconvert /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff ~/Desktop/sub.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v
```

You can inspect a sound to determine its data format by opening it in QuickTime Player and choosing Show Movie Inspector from the Movie menu.

Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in the correct format as well, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6

Answer (score 0):

To use the default sound for a notification

```swift
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

/// Set up content ...

content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

To use a custom sound, the sound file has to be stored in the **app's main bundle** OR download it and store it in the `Library/Sounds` subdirectory of the app's container directory.

The "main bundle" approach can only be used with a new application release, the "downloading the sound file" approach is more flexible and makes shipping new sounds without a new version release.